# Multi-level bullet list in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I need to create a multi-level bullet list in my .NET MAUI app which is at least 2 levels, possibly 3, even 4 levels deep.

How do I handle this in XAML or do I need to handle it in Blazor?

Comment: This is pretty broad.  You could use HTML in a webview.  You could use a StackLayout wth Labels of varying left margin.  If it needs to be data driven, use a bindable layout.  There are lots of ways you could approach it

Comment: You could try a [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label#display-html) with `TextType="Html"` for simple, static scenarios or for formatted data coming from some data source.

Comment: @Jason Using labels and adjusting left margins is a pretty interesting idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use a Grid. **ColumnDefinitions** property could be used to set different level while **RowDefinitions** could be used to set items. You could use either Absolute or Star value to set the width or height.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

For more info, you could refer to [.NET MAUI Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0).